# Absolute continuity of limiting measures

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $A_n$, $B_n$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ be finte subsets of compact set $X$ in $\mathbb C$ such that
$A_n \subset B_n$.

Let $\delta_{A_n}:= \frac{1}{|A_n|} \displaystyle\sum_{x\in A_n} \delta_x$ and $\delta_{B_n}:=\frac{1}{|B_n|} \displaystyle\sum_{x\in B_n} \delta_x$ be normalized dirac probability measures.

If $\delta_{A_n} \to \mu$ and $\delta_{B_n} \to \sigma$ as $n \to \infty$ in the weak* topology then can we say that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\sigma$?

If answer is no in general, can one suggest me reference for the weakest known sufficient condition on $A_n$ and $B_n$ (may be on $|A_n|$ and $|B_n|$) so that answer is yes?

Comment: $|A_n|\ge \alpha |B_n|$ for some $\alpha>0$ suffices.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas So in general answer is negative or not known?

Comment: what if $A_n=\{0\}$, and $B_n=\{0, 1/n,2/n,...,1\}$?

Comment: @erz Oh yes! Thanks. Could you suggest me reference for weakest sufficient condition known?

Comment: i suspect that the condition in the comment by Anthony Quas is actually necessary and sufficient

Comment: @erz : Unfortunately, your conjecture does not hold. E.g., consider $A_n=\frac1n\,[n]$ and $B_n=\frac1{n^2}\,[n^2]$, where $[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$. Then $\mu=\sigma=\text{the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$}$ while $|A_n|/|B_n|\to0$.

Comment: Clearly $|A_n| \geq \alpha|B_n|$ for some $\alpha > 0$ is not necessary, Let $X = [0,1]$ and $B_n := \{0,1/2^n,2/2^n,\ldots,2^n/2^n\}$ and $A_n = B_{n-1}$. Then $\mu = \sigma = \lambda$ and $|A_n|/|B_n| \to 0$.

Comment: Coincidence: Iosif Pinelis and I had with a difference of seconds the same idea. Strange!

Comment: @DieterKadelka : The time interval between our comments was 6 sec. :-)

Comment: so i guess one should look for a way to characterize the fact that $A_n$ is somehow evenly distributed in $B_n$

Comment: @erz : A condition like "$A_n$ is somehow evenly distributed in $B_n$" is not necessary either; consider e.g. $A_n=\frac1n\,[n]$ and $B_n=\frac1n\,[2n]$. I suspect that here, apart from the mere tautology or obvious restatements of the absolute continuity, there is no easy-to-use sufficient condition that would be close enough to being necessary.

Comment: I think the answer is that the only condition that depends on $|A_n|$ and $|B_n|$ alone is the one I gave. Otherwise the conditions would basically boil down to compute $\mu$; compute $\sigma$; test whether $\mu\ll\sigma$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas : I think this is probably right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\nu:=\sigma$. This answer, based mainly on comments by Anthony Quas, provides a necessary and sufficient condition for $\mu\ll\nu$ (the absolute continuity of $\mu$ with respect to $\nu$) in terms of $|A_n|$ and $|B_n|$, assuming that $X$ contains at least two distinct non-isolated points.

More specifically, let $K:=(k_n)$ and $L:=(l_n)$ be two sequences of natural numbers such that $k_n\to\infty$ and $k_n\le l_n$ for all $n$. 
Let us say that the pair $(K,L)$ is *good* if for all sequences $(A_n)$ and $(B_n)$ of  subsets of $X$ satisfying the conditions

1. $A_n\subseteq B_n$, $|A_n|=k_n$, and $|B_n|=l_n$ for all $n$ and
2. $\delta_{A_n}\to\mu$ and $\delta_{B_n}\to\nu$ for some probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$

we have $\mu\ll\nu$, where the convergence $\lambda_n\to\lambda$ of probability measures means that $\int f\,d\lambda_n\to\int f\,d\lambda$ for all bounded continuous functions $f$.

> Theorem. Suppose that $X$ contains at least two distinct non-isolated points. Then the pair $(K,L)$ is good if and only if $\limsup_n k_n/l_n>0$.

*Proof.* **The "if" part:** Suppose that $\limsup_n k_n/l_n>0$. Take any sequences $(A_n)$ and $(B_n)$ of subsets of $X$ satisfying the conditions 1 and 2. We then need to show that $\mu\ll\nu$. Passing to subsequences, without loss of generality we may assume that $|A_n|=k_n\ge al_n=a|B_n|$ for some $a\in(0,1)$ and all $n$. Then for all nonnegative bounded continuous functions $f$
$$a\int f\,d\mu\longleftarrow
\frac a{|A_n|}\sum_{x\in A_n}f(x)
\le\frac1{|B_n|}\sum_{x\in B_n}f(x)\longrightarrow\int f\,d\nu,\quad 
$$
whence $a\int f\,d\mu\le\int f\,d\nu$. So, by the regularity of the measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, it follows that $a\mu\le\nu$ and hence $\mu\ll\nu$, which completes the proof of the "if" part.

**The "only if" part:** Suppose that $\limsup_n k_n/l_n\not>0$, that is, $k_n/l_n\to0$. We then need to construct sequences $(A_n)$ and $(B_n)$ of subsets of $X$ satisfying the conditions 1 and 2 and such that $\mu\not\ll\nu$. Take any two distinct non-isolated points of $X$, say $x$ and $y$. Then there are sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ of points in $X$ such that $x_n\to x$, $y_n\to y$, and the points $x_1,x_2,\dots,y_1,y_2,\dots$ are all pairwise distinct. 
Let $A_n:=\{x_1,\dots,x_{k_n}\}$ and $B_n:=A_n\cup\{y_1,\dots,y_{l_n-k_n}\}$. Then the sequences $(A_n)$ and $(B_n)$ of subsets of $X$ satisfy the conditions 1 and 2 with $\mu=\delta_x$ and $\nu=\delta_y$, so that $\mu\not\ll\nu$, which completes the proof of the "only if" part and thus the proof of the theorem.

*Remark:* The condition that $X$ contains at least two distinct non-isolated points was used only in the proof of the "only if" part of the theorem.